# Referrer and origin preflight request headers in Safari are not changing when user navigates

Tags: safari, cors

I have two web pages hosted on `a.example.com` and `b.example`. Each web page is including a script with a `<script>` tag, hosted on another domain and served with correct CORS headers.

At a certain point, user navigates from `a.example.com` to `b.example.com`.

Safari has here a strange behavior: the `referrer` and `origin` headers in preflight request are filled with `a.example.com`, making the server sending a bad value in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (and so the script can't be executed).

Is there a way to force Safari browser to send correct `origin` header in that kind of scenario ?

Comment: If what is described in the question is accurate, this seems like a bad bug in Safari that should be reported rather than just worked around.

Comment: Would you mind adding a full dump of the headers received and sent for the request to the script? If not for finding a potential usage error, at least for being able to replicate? And **how** does the user navigate? By server side redirect, or client side?

Answer (score 1):

Does the cache policy for the script include `Vary: Origin`?

Respectively is there actually a second request after navigating to `b.example.com`?

If not, there is a chance that Safari is actually serving the script from cache - despite the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` policy forbidding it to access the resource. Which is a conforming behavior, if the cache policy isn't configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks @ext3h. The vary header is correctly sent, so I believe this is not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be indeed a Safari bug.

The issue is not reproductible on Safari 10.0. It repro only on Safari 9.1.1 / 9.1.3.